# How to extract text using Zend_Pdf from pdf page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf, pdftotext

Can anyone help with extracting text from a page in a pdf?

```
<?php
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::load('example.pdf');
$page = $pdf->page[0];
```

I would assume a page method would exist but I could not find anything to let me extract the contents.

Example: $page->getContents(); $page->toString(); $page->extractText();

...Help!!!! This is driving me crazy!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496191/php-pdf-2-text-problem Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Andy that this does not appear to be supported.  As an alternative, take a look at [Shaun Farrell's solution to extracting text from a PDF for use with Zend_Search_Lucene](http://www.kapustabrothers.com/2008/01/20/indexing-pdf-documents-with-zend_search_lucene/).  He uses [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/), which might also meet your needs.

Comment: xpdf will extract the text from PDFs, as long as your PDFs actually contain text of course (as opposed to scanned images). On the other hand, you might try the following as well : http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php.

Comment: The link above is dead and while I found several pages that linked to it I couldn't find another source.  I was able to use pdftotext to extract the information I needed in case someone else runs across this post.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html) it doesn't appear that this functionality is supported. Also, new text is written using the [drawText() function](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.usage.html), which appears to write images, not plain "decodable" text.

Comment: It does write 'text' rather than images but you're certainly correct, at the moment parts of a PDF can't be extracted or modified.