# PHP pdf 2 text problem

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, zend-pdf

I'm using Zend_Pdf library for extract text from pdf and I have some problems...

```
<?php
set_include_path (__DIR__ . '\data'); 
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php'; 

 // Load PDF document from a file. 
$fileName = 'carbsarticle.pdf'; 
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf($fileName); 
$pdf = Zend_Pdf::parse($pdf); 
var_dump($pdf);
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'File is not a PDF.'

I tried to download other pdf file, but the error is the same ..

**EDIT:**

```
try {
    $pdf2 = Zend_Pdf::load('test.pdf');
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This echoes: Encrypted document modification is not supported

My pdf: http://x3k.ru/test.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay just saw the usage at zend documentation

```
#
// Load a PDF document from a file
#
$pdf2 = Zend_Pdf::load($fileName);
#

#
// Load a PDF document from a string
#
$pdf3 = Zend_Pdf::parse($pdfString);
#
...
```

This is how you load a PDF file.

Comment: $pdf2 ... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Encrypted document modification is not supported' FOR ANY PDF files..

Comment: Encrypted document? Is your pdf protected by a password? Use a try-catch block around your parsing and then output the whole stacktrace of the exception to get more information about the error

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory path. May be you need to set as `set_include_path (__DIR__ . '\data\');`

Comment: @sai, I copied this file to wherever I can .. problem persists (

Comment: please paste your code, it will be helpful. Just saw the code of core zend file. "$this->_trailer          = $this->_parser->getTrailer();
". You need to set this to null, if you don't want to see that error

Comment: You probably need to set after                   $pdf= new Zend_pdf(); $pdf->properties['encoding'] = "utf-8" then do a loading.

Comment: @sai, Encrypted document modification is not supported ((

Comment: You are not modifying, but you are just setting header, to tell what kind of encoding shall zend_pdf use?

Comment: Sorry Xeka, I currently don't have access to my PHP Environment. Let me try at home and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file is copy-protected, i guess :) Use other file - say download something from internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this a while back with a pdf I received from someone.  I had to remove the password protection altogether in order for Zend to work with it at all.  Zend will not modify any encrypted docs.  I ended up getting a PDF decrypter to do the job, there's plenty out there if you've lost the original password.